# I am able to use peerjs server. I want to host my own peerjs server but it's not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, server, peerjs

my server side code

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const server = require('http').Server(app)
const io = require('socket.io')(server)
const { ExpressPeerServer } = require('peer');

const peerServer = ExpressPeerServer(server, {
  debug: true
});

app.use('/peerjs', peerServer);


server.listen(3000);
```

```
And my client-side code is
```

```
var myPeer = new Peer(undefined, {
  path: '/peerjs',
  host: '/',
  port: '3000'
})
```

But when I use this code on client side connection works

`var myPeer = new Peer(undefined)`

Also I am geeting this error in chrome dev console

***WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket&sid=sdb0qfOv9QAlFfKJAAAA' failed: Invalid frame header***

I am trying to make peer-to-peer connection for last few days and tried a lot of solutions from stack overflow  but it's not working.

I need help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by deploying my own peerjs server on heroku and then using it to make secure peer to peer connection

```
 var myPeer = new Peer(undefined, {
  host: "your-peer-server-name.herokuapp.com",
  port: 443,
  secure: true
});
```

Problem can also be solved by using different ports for local host and your peer server port, I was using 3000 for both peer connection and local host that's why it was not working.

Answer (score -1):

1. download ngrok and install
2. on open of ngrok shell type the command ngrok http your port no
   e.g(**ngrok http 3000**) and enter
   you will get something like this
3. [ngrok shell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sA1HN.png)

[after enter ngrok http 5000](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZrPnT.png)

4. put the http forwading to you API_URL
5. in peerServer host put the same url without the http://